# Using custom file handler when sharing document

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, external-sharing

I added a custom file handler for certain extension for both editing and preview on my SharePoint Online tenant.

However, when generating and sharing an anonymous link to a document of this type, the document is opened with the default SharePoint Online UI instead of my own file handler.

This is not the case when I open a file as usual from the SharePoint document library, it opens with my file handler as expected.

Is there a way to customize this behavior so that it opens in my file handler instead of the default one?